# Prevent square edges when using mask-image in a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

Kia ora! I'm trying to display some nice hero images masked with an svg to create nice and interesting shapes. The images are in a 12-column Grid element with a title and some copy in the first 7 columns, and the image in the next six. I'm using NextJS and Tailwind with Sanity.io, for reference.

My issue is that when the SVG mask flows beyond the element the image is in, it obviously clips to have a hard straight line edge. I might be approaching this the wrong way, but I'd love for the size of the image to be constrained by the SVG and the element they're in, so that the shape of the SVG isn't clipped by the parent element.

Here's some sample code:

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-12 p-4 bg-emerald-50'>
                <div className='col-span-7'> 
                    <h1 className='font-bold text-8xl text-cyan-500'>{about.title}</h1>
                    <div className='py-4 prose'>
                        <PortableText value={about.desc} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='relative col-span-5 m-1 clip-image'>
                    <Image src={urlFor(about.hero_image).url()} height={500} width={500} />
                </div>
            </div>
```

`clip-image` is:

```
.clip-image {
    mask-image: url('../public/hero.svg');
    mask-size: cover;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-position: center;
  }
```

Like I said, I think I might be approaching this in the wrong way - I think I must need to limit the size of the image to the size of the element it's in (or just choose a different image/SVG so that setting `mask-size: 100%` doesn't clip out faces) - but any other suggestions would be super appreciated!